# invalid literal for int() with base10 in django query

Tags: python, django

I am trying to import an excel file into my database. The file contains an id column which is later saved to Foreignkey filed in django model.

```
st_id = row[10]
st_data = Student.objects.get(id=st_id)
```

Now when i save this data with .save() method, it saves the data but returns an unbound error 'st_data' referenced before assignment. The traceback is `invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

Whats actually happening? It saves the correct data all right, but throws the invalid literal for int().

EDIT:
The overall concept is as follows:

```
try:
    st_id = row[10]
    print type(st_id) #this line returns both type float and str
    st_data = Student.objects.get(id=st_id)
except Exception as e:
    print e #here it throws an exception `invalid literal for int()`

st_dict = {
   'student': st_data,
}

obj = Section(**st_dict)
obj.save() #the correct data is saved to the database.
```

Comment: Could you provide more information, maybe a hint of the excel, or maybe the save, etc.

Comment: Because `row[10]` is not integer.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a float as an integer.

Comment: yes it returns a type float. I tried with int(row[10]) but didnt change anything. The error invalid literal for int still persists.

Comment: change `print e` to `print e, row[10]` to see what value causes the exception

Comment: print row[10] gives 4.0 which is clearly a float. This  `int(row[10])` didnt helped me either

Comment: you can't do `int('4.0')` ...this would work `int(float(row[10]))` note that it truncates the float (i.e rounds down so `4.7` will come out as `4`)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your row doesn't contains int's.

To fix it, just try:

```
st_data = Student.objects.get(id=int(st_id))
```